# ShareThis facebook share description not working

Tags: facebook, sharethis

i added:

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="This is a test title"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="This is a test decription of my shared link"/>
```

on the `<head>` part of my page but this is the outcome of my share.

[image]

what am i missing here to add a custom description and title for my share link?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i came to find out that my meta for og:url wasn't right, i found this out by using the facebook debugger tool.

Input your page url and it will show you the information it could retrieve, or else it will tell you why it couldn't find the date

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug